# Can an iPad screen be displayed on a Windows PC for accessing iMessage?

Tags: ipad

I am new to Apple ecosystem of devices and services. I am trying to find a way to use iMessage service at work.

So far I only have an iPhone XS Max and an Apple Watch Series 4. I have a PC running Windows 10 at work, that is about 8 years old, and a Windows laptop that is about 6 months old.

I wish to use my desktop to communicate with people with images from the PC or texting, so that my workflow could involve not picking up the iPhone constantly.

I was considering getting an iPad Pro 2017 and plug it up to the PC, then display the image as a window on my Windows 10 PC. Is there a way of doing this?

The main goal is just to continue to use iMessage on my Windows 10 PCs.

Any other suggestions would also be considered. I have read articles about getting a Mac mini and use remote desktop from Google Chrome to do that, or run macOS in a virtual machine on windows. My Windows 10 PC is too old and limited to only 8 GB of memory.

Answer (score 1):

iMessage which was subsequently rebranded as Messages is a messaging service available for Apple devices.

It is not available for other desktop and mobile operating systems. It is not possible to use iMessage on Windows by installing any app or Web based client.

> I was considering getting an iPad Pro 2017 and plug it up to the PC, then display the image as a window on my Windows 10 PC. Is there a way of doing this?

It is possible via 3rd party tools to display the screen frame (output) of an iPad on a Windows PC, however, it’s not possible to operate iOS (software running on iPad) via this way.

Accessing a Mac mini over remote connection should work fine, as it’s available on both iOS and macOS. As long as you are able to run and access macOS, you should be able to access iMessage service all right.

If the only thing you are looking for is to look for an easy way to exchange iMessage (from the comfort of using physical keyboard) using it on a Mac is your best bet. There’s no point in trying to connect and access an iPad via a desktop computer.

Comment: I understand the limitations that Apple has done to the software, so I am looking for alternatives with Apple hardware. Do you have any suggestions of connecting a Ipad to a windows 10 and have a Window open on Windows 10 and use my keyboard and mouse on the Windows 10 PC and copy and paste images or text on the Window of the Windows 10 pc that is the Ipad?

Comment: You might consider getting a Mac mini, which you could vnc into and send stuff that way. I was going to say this would be more expensive, but they actually both start at $799 new right now

Comment: Well, I was hoping there was an application to allow copying from Windows and pasting to the Windowed Ipad on Windows 10 pc. The only thing I could find was more of a displaying of the Ipad on windows 10 with Air play.

Comment: @JonCapps There’s no such app that provides the feature that you are looking for. If you are using a Mac, it’s possible to copy paste text and images across your computer and iPad. Images can be also be exchanged via AirDrop.